# How to add Firebase Storage to Cloud Functions for Firebase? And then use `getDownloadURL`?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get a Firebase Storage download URL (with long-lived token) from Cloud Functions for Firebase. I'm guessing two possible issues:

1. I'm using [Google Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html), not Firebase Cloud Storage.
2. `getDownloadURL()` doesn't work from Cloud Functions.

I'm looking at the [documentation for Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and I see sections for

- iOS+
- Android
- Web
- Flutter
- Admin
- C++
- Unity
- Security & Rules

Why do I not see section for Cloud Functions for Firebase? Is `Admin` the same as Cloud Functions for Firebase?

There's a section [Extend Cloud Storage with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) but it's about triggering Cloud Functions from Storage, not using Cloud Functions to do stuff in Storage.

Let's try to get that download URL. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#web-version-8_1) says to do this:

```js
var storage = firebase.storage();
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg');
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
     console.log(url);
  });
```

But I create a Storage client with Google Cloud Storage:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'abc123',
  authDomain: 'my-app.firebaseapp.com',
  credential: admin.credential.cert({serviceAccount}),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'gs://my-project.appspot.com',
});

const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'gs://my-project.appspot.com';
const bucket = storage.bucket('my-project.appspot.com');
```

I can write a file to Firebase Storage:

```js
await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(destFileName).save(file['rawBody']);
```

But this doesn't work:

```js
await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(destFileName).getDownloadURL()
   .then((url) => {
     console.log("Download URL: " + url);
     return url;
   });
```

That throws an error:

```
TypeError: storage.bucket(...).file(...).getDownloadURL is not a function
```

That's making me suspect that `getDownloadURL` isn't available for Cloud Functions.

Let's try this:

```js
var storageRef = admin.firebase.storage().ref(destFileName);
await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
   .then(function (url) {
        console.log(url);
   });
```

That throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storage')
```

That's worse, it's crashing on `storage` in the first line and not even getting to `getDownloadURL`.

Let's try this:

```js
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL(bucketName + '/' + destFileName);
await gsReference.getDownloadURL()
   .then(function (url) {
        console.log("Download URL: " + url);
        return url;
   });
```

That throws the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storage')
```

Same problem, it can't get past `storage` in the first line.

Comment: Yes. Codes in `Admin` can be used in cloud function when you initializeApp with firebase-admin.

Comment: See the top 2 answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, you're right, the second answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase is excellent! The author is clearly a genius, if somewhat forgetful. :-)

Comment: OMG, I hadn't even noticed that.  --- Kudos for being reintroduced to your own answer Thomas! 

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into the same problem last time, and you are right `getDownloadURL()` does not work in cloud function.

This is the [other way round](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) to get the downloadURL of a file in Cloud Storage that I am using currently, it basically [generates a signed download url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20754279/9499523) with expiration duration.

```js
exports.signedUrl = functions.region("asia-southeast1").https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
    const storage = new Storage({ projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID", keyFilename: "./serviceAccountKey.json" });
    const bucketName = "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME";
    
    generateV4ReadSignedUrl("YOUR_FILE_PATH").catch(console.error);   
    
    async function generateV4ReadSignedUrl(filename) {
        const options = {
            version: "v4",
            action: "read",
            expires: Date.now() + 2 * 60 * 1000, // 2 minutes
        };
        const [url] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).getSignedUrl(options);
        console.log(`Generated GET signed URL: ${url}`);
        return cors()(request, response, () => {
            response.send(url);
        });
    }
});
```